# Error DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, date-format

me encuentro con el siguiente problema, cree un método donde tengo dos textfields, uno para introducir una fecha(txt_desde) y el otro donde sale automáticamente la fecha un mes después(txt_hasta).El código es el siguiente:

```java
    private void fechaPasar() {

        if (datos1.equals("1 MES")) {

            DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            var dateTime = LocalDate.parse(txt_desde.getText(), dateFormat);
            var newDateTime = dateTime.plusMonths(1);
            String resultado = newDateTime.format(dateFormat);
            txt_hasta.setText(resultado);

        }
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta el método me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2' could not be parsed at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
    at ventanas.Cobertura2.fechaPasar(Cobertura2.java:4527)
```

Alguien me podría ayudar, desde ya les agradezco.

Comment: El error te está diciendo que la llamada `txt_desde.getText()` devuelve `"2"`. Ese valor no se puede procesar como una fecha y lanza una excepción

Comment: Ya he intentado con jcalendar pero no cumple con un requisito esencial para quien me pidió el programa, ya que jcalendar tiene en cuenta los meses de 31 días y yo necesito que el día del resultado sea el mismo que el de origen solo que un mes después

Comment: que fecha le estas poniendo para que te de ese error? Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]